# Unable to execute parallel run on Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: bamboo

I am trying to execute multiple run parallel but configured Jobs in one plan are being executed sequentially. I have configured it for parallel run according to the link https://confluence.atlassian.com/bamboo/configuring-concurrent-builds-289277193.html .But not worked.

If I am doing anything wrong, please give the solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

More details are needed to effectively answer your question (# of agents, how many are capable of running the tasks, etc), but you can follow this advice:

Make sure that you have different agents available to execute each job and that the ones available have the necessary capabilities to run those jobs. For example, if you have two jobs that you expect to run in parallel, but only 1 agent is capable of building them, then they're going to run sequentially.